# How to get custom table row headers and values on a Apex Page Table?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I am trying to have a tabular display of data using (month and year) as the column header and have text boxes as the values But am not able to see the text boxes.

My vpf :

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="Revenue Forecast (Column Based)">


        <apex:pageBlockTable id="table1" value="{!columnContent}" var="cc">

            <apex:repeat value="{!MonthAndYearBreakdownByProjectStartAndEndDates}" var="mybd">
                    <apex:column>
                         <apex:facet name="header">
                              {! mybd }
                         </apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>

            </apex:repeat>
             <apex:column value="{!cc}"> </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

My Apex Code:

```
public class revenueForecastExtension {

    private final Opportunity oppor;

    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public revenueForecastExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.oppor = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public Set<String> getColumnContent() {
        Set<String> columnContent = new Set<String>();
        columnContent.add('<input id="theTextInput" type="text" name="theTextInput" />');
        return columnContent;
    }

    public Set<String> getMonthAndYearBreakdownByProjectStartAndEndDates() {
        Date d1 = oppor.Project_Start_Date__c;
        Date d2 = oppor.Project_End_Date__c;
        Map<Integer,String> monthNameMap=new Map<Integer, String>{1 =>'January', 2=>'February', 3=>'March', 4=>'April', 5=>'May',
                                                                    6=>'June', 7=>'July', 8=>'August', 9=>'September',10=>'October',
                                                                    11=>'November', 12=>'December'};

        Set<String> monthYearSet = new Set<String>();

        while(d1 < d2)
            {
                monthYearSet.add(monthNameMap.get(d1.Month()) + ' ' + d1.Year());
                d1 = d1.AddMonths(1);
            }
        return monthYearSet;
    }

    public PageReference quicksave() {
        update oppor;
        PageReference orderPage = new PageReference('/apex/revenueForecast?&id='+oppor.Id);
        orderPage.setRedirect(true);
        return orderPage;
    }

}
```

Here is my screen capture:

[image: Missing Column Values]

As you can see I am missing column values. Ideally I should see a text box under each column. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not 100% sure I got your intention right, but here goes.

You're version is saying creating a table with a columns for each period, but no data defined, and then a final column with the `input` tag as the content.

To have the input be the content you'd want this

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Revenue Forecast (Column Based)">
<apex:pageBlockTable id="table1" value="{!MonthAndYearBreakdownByProjectStartAndEndDates}" var="mybd">
    <apex:column>
         <apex:facet name="header">
              {!mybd}
         </apex:facet>
         <input id="theTextInput" type="text" name="theTextInput"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

There are other things you're going to run into I expect, first that input tag isn't going to be much help if it's not tied to anything in the backend. Second, if you keep going with returning the input tag as a string, stop, it's just going to print the raw html as a string which isn't what I expect you want.